# Preserving model in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. I'm relatively new to ASP.NET MVC 4. Currently, I'm trying to build a basic Task list app.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model = new TaskModel();
  return View("~/Views/Task.cshtml", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TaskModel model)
{
  if (model.TaskName.Length == 0)
  {
     // Display error message
  }
  else 
  {
    // Save to database
    // Write success message
  }
  return View("~/Views/Task.cshtml", model);
}
```

If there is an error, I display an error message on the screen. My problem is, the previously entered values in the view are not shown. The entire view is blank.How do I preserve the values in the view in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use TempData for this.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model = new TaskModel();
  TempData["task"] = model;
  return View("~/Views/Task.cshtml", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var task = (TaskModel)TempData["task"];
  UpdateModel(task);
  if (model.TaskName.Length == 0)
  {
     // Display error message
  }
  else 
  {
    // Save to database
    // Write success message
  }

  TempData["task"] = task;
  return View("~/Views/Task.cshtml", model);
}
```

MVC works different than WebForms, since there is no concept of 'controls', you have to preserve the state yourself. Another option if you don't want to use TempData is to use an LosFormatter to Serialize your controls into a hidden HTML field. This would replicate the functionality of ViewState in ASP.NET WebForms